# Trouble using Cocalc with Latex

Tags: sagetex, cocalc

I am having trouble running the following code, which works in CoCalc but will not work in Latex, even though it is the tex. output not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
p = 3.14
r = randint(1,10)
output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\draw[fill=none](0,0) circle (1.0) node [black,yshift=-1.5cm] {};"
output += r"\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (1 pt) node [above] {\tiny o};"
output += r"\draw[](0,0) -- (1,0) node [midway,above] {%s};"%(r)
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}

\noindent Circumference = $2\times \pi \times r = 2\pi(\sage{r})$.
Using the approximation of $\pi \approx \sage{p.n(digits=3)}$ we get a decimal   answer 
 of $\sage{(2*p*r).n(digits=4)}$ units.
 \end{document}
```

Comment: most people here won't have sage (or will choose not to run unknown code via `shell-escape`)  can you show the exact error from the latex log in a code block, and also if possible the latex file that sage generates here.

Comment: I don't know sagetex but is `%s};"%(r)` taken as a comment in this environment?

Comment: that's the strange thing I don't get a console error it just doesn't run in Latex but works fine in CoCalc and the code looks fine to me.

Comment: maybe its a problem I should put on overflow?

Comment: OK I'm out then but wait a while there are sagetex users here, perhaps someone will answer.

Comment: thanks anyway, hope you have a nice day.

Comment: 1.After you run LaTeX (output should be to pdf not dvi file) your pdf output should have some question marks (which will be filled in later with the info Sage provides). If not there should be an error. What is it? 2. Next,when you run Sage on `.sagetex.sage`, was there an error given? If so what is it? You can also check the `.sout` file: Sage will tell you the errors there as well. 3.When you now run LaTeX on your `.tex` file, what errors have you gotten? LaTex errors mentioned in `log`file You have to be specific as to what has gone wrong for us to figure out what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Please provide more detail: how are you running LaTeX? From the Terminal, via TeXShop, some other way? What did you do to try to make `sagetex.sty` known to the TeX engine?

Comment: Hi @JohnPalmieri I Have followed all the instructions on the sage site and it runs but It just gives me ?? instead of numbers, and when I try to tell Tex were to find the .sty file it just doesn't do anything, using the code in terminal given on their site. I just don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly did you do and what's the error message? To get SageTeX to work, you have to install Sage on your computer and make the style files available to your LaTeX distribution.

The basic idea: first run LaTeX to extract the code, then run Sage to process the code and capture the result, then run LaTeX again. The second time around, sagetex sees that there are results available and it will insert these snippets in your final document.

Docs: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html

Comment: Thanks @Harald Schilly here is what I get https://pastebin.com/tBm3Efyd

Comment: as your log clearly shows `! LaTeX Error: File \`sagetex.sty' not found.`  so you need to install it before you use it. @PaulA (I did suggest you showed the error from the log in my initial comment:-)

Comment: @PaulA please look into the tutorial. it has a [whole section](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html#make-sagetex-known-to-tex) about "Make SageTeX known to TeX" explaining various ways how connect `sagetex.sty` (which is in sage) with your latex setup

Answer (score 0):

Note that one part of the Sage documentation is outdated and will be fixed in the next release (see https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/34219), and that could have misled you.

From the Terminal:

```
% kpsewhich sagetex.sty
```

should return nothing, because it currently can't find the file "sagetex.sty".

```
% kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
/Users/jpalmier/Library/texmf
```

This tells me that I should add style files to this directory. You have several options here, including copying the file or making a link. First go to that directory:

```
% cd `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`
```

I would first create a directory `tex` (if it doesn't already exist), and then within that, `latex`:

```
% ls # to check whether 'tex' exists
% mkdir tex # create it if it doesn't
% cd tex
% ls
% mkdir latex # if it doesn't exist already
% cd latex
```

Now find your Sage installation. On my machine it's in my Desktop folder. Either copy or link the relevant files to the current directory. Link:

```
% ln -s /Users/jpalmier/Desktop/sage/venv/share/texmf/tex/latex/sagetex
```

(This is where the error in the Sage documentation enters: it says "local" when it should say "venv".) Copy:

```
% cp -R /Users/jpalmier/Desktop/sage/venv/share/texmf/tex/latex/sagetex .
```

Test it out:

```
% kpsewhich sagetex.sty
/Users/jpalmier/Library/texmf/tex/latex/sagetex/sagetex.sty
```